# Login for two types of users e.g customer and admin

Tags: php, authentication

I have a login set up for one user but I am looking to add in an additional login for an admin using the same login page.The admin will be able to access all the pages the user can but also some additional pages. I'm wondering if anyone can explain to me how to do this. Thanks.

login.php

```
session_start();
$usr = new Users;
$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );
if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
header( 'Location: /user/' ) ;
$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];

} else {
echo '<center>'."<font color='red'>Sorry, Incorrect Username or Password <br> Please Try Again </br> </font>".'</center>';
}
}
```

Response.php

```
<?php
    //set off all error for security purposes
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    //define some contstant
    define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname1" );
    define( "DB_USERNAME", "" );
    define( "DB_PASSWORD", "" );
    define( "CLS_PATH", "class" );

    //include the classes
    include_once( CLS_PATH . "/user.php" );


?>
```

Top of each page:

```
<?php

session_start();

// redirects to user to the login.php page if user is not logged in

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){
header("location:  /login.php"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: well when a user register on your site u can give him status as customer and admin and according to their status you can redirect them to pages related to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way isnt secure. Always keep the admin file separate. I would suggest you to make an addon domain and place all the admin related files there.

To answer you question, just add another field in the sql table which states the level of the user. Check the user level and then display the content you want to display. Use if conditions to check the level and display the links,data accordingly.

Also on the view able by admin only pages check is the user is admin or not .If not the exit to the home page

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to keep separate files for admin. Admins meant to be managing contents on the website and has a private url. So in best practices you can create another folder for example "admin-cp" , and put all the pages related to admin in there.

But in your case, you can save a flag in session which will tell you if the user is normal user or admin user, and based on that flag, show links or whatever access way you use for admins. Also on that pages, check if the user is admin, then ok, else redirect user to home page or other page if loged in. The flag can be like "isAdmin" with value 1 or 0.